# Поиск всех совпадений в строке

Tags: c

Есть такая задача: есть строка. Потом пользователь вводит ещё одну строку. И нужно сделать поиск в строке по подстроке(ту что ввёл пользователь), и вывести кол-во совпадений. Например исходная строка: "50002150", пользователь вводит "50". Ему выводит: 2.

Была такая идея, сделать с помощь функции strstr. Но там идёт просто поиск. Поэтому можно сделать так: организовать цикл и в цикле вызывать  strstr до тех пор, пока не начнёт возвращать FALSE. Тем временем в цикле также вырезать из исходной строки найденное вхождение и считать кол-во выполнений цикла. Но мне кажется всё можно сделать намного проще, какая-нибудь функция есть, помогите пожалуйста.

Мой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <math.h>
#include "funcsLib.h"
char finds[255];
char *buf; 
int q=0;
math_func F;
//Куча кода, который, думаю, вам не нужен
scanf("%d",&func);
F.calc(func);
buf = strstr(F.result_string,finds);
printf("%s",buf);
while(buf!=NULL){
buf=strstr(buf+1,finds);
q++;
 }
 printf("%d",q);
```

В струтуре F.result_string это char result_string[255].
F.calc:

```
sprintf(result_string, "%s", "");
for(int i=0;i<=count;i++){
    //Опять лишний код
sprintf(result_string, "%s/%lf-%lf-%lf", result_string,res[i].x,res[i].a,res[i].val.num);
 }
```

Вот в этом коде цикл тот бесконечен, где я не прав?
Почему-то не могу комментить)) [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), Да, это учебная программа, Вы очень сложный какой-то код предоставили))

Comment: как раз strstr и используйте. А строку вырезать не нужно. Просто вместо указателя на начало строки, передавайте указатель на начало строки плюс текущее смещение. Если ещё проще - strstr возвращает указатель на позицию, где нашлась строка. Достаточно добавить ещё единичку и можно передавать для дальнейшего поиска.

Comment: Такой цикл почему-то не рабоатет и бесконечен:  
while(buf!=NULL){
   buf=strstr(buf+1,finds);
   q++;
  }  
Помогите, скажите как правильно сделать

Comment: а у меня работает. Я только буквально пару строк добавил - переменные объявить да результат вывести.

    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(void) {
     char * buf = "12345123312312322";
     char * finds = "123";
     int q = 0;
     while(buf!=NULL){ buf=strstr(buf+1,finds); q++; }
     printf("q = %d\n", q);
     return 0;
    }

Comment: Вот этим мне и не нравится СИ, почти одинаковые кода, но у меня не работает. finds у меня считывается scanf, а buf складывается функцией sprintf в цикле.

Comment: Что значит "почти одинаковые"? Покажите свой код, наверняка там логические ошибки есть. В любом языке нужно не тыкаться наугад, а понимать что пишешь и как оно работает. А "язык не нравится" от человека, который даже базовых вещей не знает, звучит смешно...

Comment: Показал свой код. Я в программировании 5 лет: php,python,java. И в них такого как в СИ гемороя не было, всегда всё понятно и самые простые вещи легко реализуются. Здесь же постоянный бред. Ещё компилятор постоянно гавном занимается, то scanf_s ему надо, то классы перестаёт видеть, нужно их удалить и по новой напечатать (Visual Studio). Т.ч. Ничего смешного, поматал он мне нервы за пол года больше чем за всю мою жизнь.

Comment: Спасибо, понял в чём проблема)) В result_string у меня забивается больше чем 255 символов и из-за этого все проблемы) Увеличил до 1000 - всё заработало, всем спасибо))

Comment: Во-первых, в C нету классов, так что здесь вы, судя по всему, о C++. Во-вторых, в корне неверное выделять под строку буфер фиксированной длины. Примените мозг и _подсчитайте_, сколько символов нужно выделять, вы же программист.

Comment: @mctrane, я не понимаю, что Вы **хотели** сказать, написав 

Вот в этом коде цикл тот бесконечен

    for(int i=0;i<=count;i++){
    //Опять лишний код
      sprintf(result_string, "%s/%lf-%lf-%lf",    result_string,res[i].x,res[i].a,res[i].val.num);
    }

Можете связный код, который у Вас не работает привести?

--

Кстати, тот код поиска в buf не работает, если надо искать с первого байта.

Я бы его так

    for (q = 0; buf = strstr(buf + (q ? 1 : 0), finds); q++);


нарисовал.

Comment: Прочел остальные комментарии.

@mctrane, надеюсь это учебная программа. 

На всякий случай, `sprintf` возвращает количество выведенных байт. Поэтому более эффективный (не переписывает строку саму в себя на каждой итерации) и более безопасный код может выглядеть, например, так:

    #define INIT_SIZE 80
    #define MAX_OUT 30

    size_t rssz = INIT_SIZE, lrs = 0;
    char *rs = malloc(rssz);
    *rs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      if (lrs + MAX_OUT + 1 > rssz)
        rs = realloc(rs, rssz += INIT_SIZE);
      lrs += sprintf(rs + lrs, "/%d-%d-%d", i, i * i, i * i * i);
    }